# IIS 7 with PHP in Domain with Windows Authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, active-directory, iis

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 x64b installed with IIS 7, PHP 5.5.

This server is added to domain `exampledomain` , so I have win authentication enabled and all others disabled. I left the two default providers NTLM and negotiate, I granted `IIS_IUSRS` read access to `wwwroot`.

So far it has worked **for me only** as I am added to the Administrators group which has read/write access to `wwwroot` folder.

Yet, when someone else is trying to connect, he gets a credentials window and when he puts the domain name and password he cannot get access to the page.

The issue is solved when I add read permission to "Domain users" - then all works fine.

BUT. My issue is that if one opens windows explorer and types `\\servername\wwwroot` one can see the files and read them.  I have never configured IIS before so I know I miss some really important thing. How can I solve the file visibility problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why your "wwwroot" folder is shared with Windows File and Print Sharing (the service that is allowing you to access the server's hard disk drive with the UNC path `\\servername\wwwroot`). It doesn't need to be shared with Windows File Print Sharing for IIS to server an application out of that directory.

If the server is something that predates you then there may be some reason in the past and you should probably go digging for documentation.

If you want to live dangerously, remove the "Sharing" from the "wwwroot" folder. An easy way to do that is to right-click the folder in Windows Explorer, go to the "Sharing" tab, and disable sharing. (Depending on whether you left UAC enabled you may have to elevate.)

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to assume for some awful reason, you need to have the wwwroot directory shared (perhaps for publishing, I don't know...). Also, I am going to assume this is Windows 2008.

1. Right click on the folder, click properties
2. Click the Sharing tab
3. Click Advanced Sharing
4. Click the permissions button
5. Remove Everyone
6. Add Domain Admins
7. Select full control

Please understand, if you are sharing the directory for publishing there is 100 other, more secure ways to publish the site. If you don't care and want to use sharing, the above will fix you.

Linuxx

Comment: Thanks, i removed Domain Users and IIS_IUSRS from share and left there only 3 ppl which need change code and added via permission domain users and IIS_IUSRS and it works perfectly, thanks for help still learning and rarely Google not helps ;)